# Why is my previous reputation value not reported?

Tags: support, bug, reputation-leagues, user-rank

On my profile, I get a link like [top 14% of this month](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/month/stackoverflow/2012-03-01/674374#674374); clicking on it, I am redirected to a reputation league display, where my month rank, change in rank, total reputation, and month reputation are displayed.

The value in change for me appears as **"not previously ranked"**. I have been member for more than a year, but for those users who are member for less than a year, it is showing up the change value.

What is the criteria used here? Why the previous value is not showing up for me?

Comment: The actual behavior is not the expected one, especially because for some users, e.g. [BalusC](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/month/stackoverflow/2012-03-01/157882?sort=reputationchange#157882), the league says "0 change." That is what I would always expect to see. "not previously ranked" is what I would expect to read, when a user didn't have an account in the previous period of time.

Comment: You seem to have had no rep changes in February, so in Febrary, you haven't been listed in the ranks.

Comment: No reputation change doesn't mean having no rank.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Check [the February league](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/month/stackoverflow/2012-02-01/674374#674374). He didn't appear there.

Comment: That is the problem: He should appear there too, as he has already reputation, and he has had an account since March 2011. If my reputation doesn't change, but all the other users get 100 points more, my rank does change.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I thought the week/month leagues would only list users with change, but apparently [that is not so](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/month/stackoverflow/2012-01-01?sort=reputationchange&page=1920). Bug, then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You had no reputation changes in February, so you haven't appeared in the February league. Now in March, you appear, but when the rank of February is looked up for the "previous" column, it is not found, hence "not previously ranked".

It is not literally correct, since you have been previously ranked, just not in the previous month. I think, however, that that is a too rare occurrence for the team to change it.

On further investigation, I saw that users with no reputation changes are listed in the monthly leagues, so while your absence from the February league was likely caused by you having no reputation changes in that month, you should have appeared. A bug report seems due.